# Why stop the common language runtime (CLR) while exporting Excel File in ssrs report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, rdl, ssrs-2019

Why stop the common language runtime (CLR) while exporting Excel file from a SSRS report, but Excel file is generated successfully. Is there any solution? Please help

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Do you have an ASP.NET application that is throwing an exception when invoking some method to export an Excel file? It would probably help if you included the source code that is causing the issue. See [ask].